# Is there a better way to manage mounts in a UseEffect react hook then declaring a local variable every time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

In my react-native project, I am calling different social logins like Facebook and Google. When the button is clicked, the sign in starts, authenticates, and a new stack is rendered based on if a user is set. I was originally running into the warning :

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

So I modified my code and ended up with this:

```js
  const handleFacebookLogin = async () => {
    await facebookLogin().then(error => {
      setError(error);
    });
  };
  const handleGoogleLogin = async () => {
    await googleLogin().then(error => {
      setError(error);
    });
  };
  const handleEmailLogin = async () => {
    await login(email, password).then(error => {
      setError(error);
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    signInLoading && handleEmailLogin();
    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
      setSignInLoading(false);
    };
  }, [signInLoading]);
  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    facebookLoading && handleFacebookLogin();
    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
      setFacebookLoading(false);
    };
  }, [facebookLoading]);
  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    googleLoading && handleGoogleLogin();
    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
      setGoogleLoading(false);
    };
  }, [googleLoading]);
```

I call setLoadings() on buttonclicks, then set isMounted=true every time.

This just seems repetitive and unnecessary needing to declare "isMounted" every time. Is there an easier or more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove repetition by creating a hook:

```
const useAuth = (loginFn) => {

  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    loading && loginFn().then(setError);
    return () => {
      setLoading(false);
    };
  }, [loading]);

  return [
    setLoading,
    error,
  ];
};

const UseLike = () => {
  // Since it looks like you're using setLoading to trigger
  // the login, this will do the same things.
  const [setFacebookLoading, facebookError] = useAuth(facebookLogin);
};
```

But the code you provided doesn't use the isMounted variable anywhere.

Comment: Oh shoot you're right! Hm, I wonder why im not getting that error anymore.. Thanks for the hook suggestion I'll do that!

Comment: So looks like returning the setLoading in the useffect was equivalent to managing a mounted state. Before I wasnt returning the setLoading in useffect and I was getting that error. Still a little confused as to why I need to return out of useEffect though. Ill work on that hook now! Thanks for the help @windowsill

Comment: The return value of an effect is a cleanup function. In this case it doesn't really do anything. Instead I would have loginFn().then(setError).finally(()=>setLoading (false)). Btw it's kinda weird to have a promise resolve with an error value. Instead I would have it reject with the error instead.

Comment: Good point I'll make that change! also it seems that returning setLoading(false) removed the warning I was getting. @windowsill